# Difference between interpolation method - give me some function

Tags: interpolation

What are some functions that gives vastly different results when interpolated with spline, in comparison to linear or to polynomial interpolation? For example i tried with sigmoid and bump function, both gives almost same results, no matter which interpolating method i use

Comment: I had some problem interpolating $\ln(-\ln x)$ with polynomials for  $\int\limits_0^1\ln(-\ln x)\,dx$, maybe you can try something on this one?

Comment: this function that takes domain [0:1] and rest is undefined?

Comment: For real-valued $\log$ and $x\in \mathbb{R}$ I think yes: for $\ln(-\ln(x))$ to be real we need $-\ln(x)>0$ so $\ln(x)<0$, so $x<1$, but $x>0$ for the inner $\ln$ to be real. Thus $0<x<1$.

Answer (score 0):

i tried with function sugested above:
$$
f(x) = ln(-ln(x))
$$
But there is not much difference between interpolation methods,as you can see there is only difference and the ends of domain. 
[gnuplot comparison of interpolation methods](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFm7V.png)

Arent there any functions that have more visible difference?

Comment: I think you should update the question though rather than posting this as an answer, sorry. The plot differs rather much for $x\in[0.8,1)$ on the picture. What order of polynomials did you use? I tried 61th, but couldn't get enough accuracy though.